# How to return http statuscodes in php?

Tags: php, http, http-status

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [return a specific http status code with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402067/return-a-specific-http-status-code-with-php)

How can I programmatically send specific http statuscodes with php?
Is there any Method or even a class for this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6164319/1395993 for an elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header()` function is what you need.

`void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )`

Place it right after the first `<?php` tag for the script rendering the response output.

You should refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`header()`](http://php.net/header.php) function:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

Put that before any output of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Send a [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) *before* you send anything else to the client. Some possible status headers follow:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

// Page was not found:
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');

// Access forbidden:
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');

// The page moved permanently should be used for
// all redrictions, because search engines know
// what's going on and can easily update their urls.
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');

// Server error
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');

// header for telling the browser that the content
// did not get changed
header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
```